# Data Preprocessing, how separate background from image to detect animals?

Tags: classification, image-classification

Hello I'm looking for some advice making a animal Classifier from trap cams, I applied SIFT to detect points of interested but it turns out that most of the points were in the background and less in the animals. My intention is to recognize animals from a dataset, any ideas that you can bring me to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Images are something like this and the keypoints : 
[image]

Any other options or suggestions? to change the way I'm going now.

Comment: You can use [Robust PCA](https://statweb.stanford.edu/~candes/papers/RobustPCA.pdf) and also [here](https://github.com/dlaptev/RobustPCA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do some Background Subtraction on the images. If you have the Background image without the animal, you can simply subtract it from the current image to get just the animal.
Once you have just the animal, you can apply SIFT or CNNs or whatever.
This is called **frame differencing**.

[image]

If you don't have the background image, you can try methods like [this](http://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/db/d5c/tutorial_py_bg_subtraction.html) provided by opencv

Basically what you are looking for is background subtraction/foreground detection.

Hope this helps.

image source: http://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html

Comment: I suspect the OP's background will be more noisy and varied than the example due to lighting changes, movement of vegetation etc. Hopefully they can set the camera trap to take e.g. hourly photos so that they have a close match for lighting available.